# How to prove $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\geq\sum_{k=0}^{m}{(\frac{n-m}{n})^k\cdot \frac{1}{k!}}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq m$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

How do I prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\geq \sum_{k=0}^{m}{\left(\frac{n-m}{n}\right)^k\cdot \frac{1}{k!}}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq m$?

What I observed:

Let $q:=\frac{n-m}{n}$, then $q\in (0,1)$.  Does that help me in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: binomial expand...

Comment: Sorry, I had a spelling error in the question. It has now been updated. Anyways, could you please elaborate - this problem will probably hunt me in my dreams...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Binomial formula,
$$
(1+\frac1n)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}1^{n-k}(\frac{1}{n})^k=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} (\frac{1}{n})^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \geq \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k!} (\frac{1}{n})^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
$$
It remains to show that $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\geq (n-m)^k$ for all $m\leq n$.

EDIT: As pointed out by @LutzL, since $k\leq m$, we have 
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n\times(n-1)\times...\times(n-k+1)\geq (n-m)\times(n-m)\times...\times (n-m)= (n-m)^k
$$
since every single term is $\geq n-m.$

Comment: No. You are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! But.. I mentioned that I had a spelling error within the answer. It actually is $\sum_{k=0}^{m}$ not $n$. Does that change anything?...

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic For $k\le m$ one gets $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n(n-1)...(n-k+1)\ge(n-m)^k$, for $k>m$ a lower bound is $0$, shortening the sum to the upper index bound $m$.

Comment: Hmm, you guys don't seem to agree...

Comment: Sorry, I now understand. I confused myself!